# TYPO3 8.7 converting FAL uid to path

Tags: typo3, fluid, fal

I've upgraded an ext. from TYPO 6.2 to 8.7 based on the fe_users table. But now image is not showing - only an id. Name and other information are showing correct.

How do I convert the uid to image path? I have followed the instructions on
https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/ImageViewHelper.html

the result is

This is my code

```
    <f:for each="{feUsers}" as="feUser" key="number" iteration="itemIteration"> 
 <div class="feuser">       
  <f:if condition="{feUser.image}">
    <f:image
     treatIdAsReference="1"
     src="uploads/pics/{feUser.image}"
     title="{feUser.name}"
     alt="{feUser.name}"
     maxWidth="159"
     maxHeight="220"
     width="159c"
     height="220c"
     crop="true"
     cropVariant="default"
    />
   </f:if>
 </div>
</for>
```

Comment: Can you please post your TCA configuration of the `image` field in `fe_users` table?

Comment: Try using `src="{feUser.image}"` (without the path) in case your images in `uploads/` have been migrated to the FAL storage at `fileadmin/` (or any other FAL storage).

Comment: I have no TCA configuration in my extension for the image field in the fe_users table. Should I have that?

Comment: src="{feUser.image}" the result i src="1"

Answer (score 0):

you have mixed multiple possibilities:
it is about your first two parameters:

```
<f:image
  treatIdAsReference="1"
  src="uploads/pics/{feUser.image}"
  :
```

if you want to use the FAL-id don't add an path (as said by Oliver Hader)

but the better option would be to avoid also the uid and use objects.

In the reference you mentioned you find the attribute `image` which needs an object in the value. so you should use:

```
<f:image
  image="{feUser.image}"
  :
```

Comment: Ok. I see. So it should work if I change to 
    <f:image 
      image="{feUser.image}" 
      title="{feUser.name}"/>
but it doesn't. Could it be my Model or my TCA?

Comment: this is from my Model

 /**
  * Returns the image
  *
  * @return null
  */
 public function getImage() {
  return $this->image;
 }

Comment: maybe you can identify something more if you debug your data: `<f:debug title="user">{feUser}</f:debug><f:debug title="user image">{feUser.image}</f:debug>`